# Must write alert before event is fired

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with a jquery snippet when users click on a table called winners. The code

```
 $('#winners tr').click(function() {
      alert(223);
    });
```

only fires if I put an alert before this code snippet like so:

```
  alert(1);
  $('#winners tr').click(function() {
    alert(223);
   });
```

The whole code is shown below. The problem is the code snippet at the bottom.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("jquery", "1.7.1");

  function listen(last_modified, etag) {
       $.ajax({
           'beforeSend': function(xhr) {
               xhr.setRequestHeader("If-None-Match", etag);
               xhr.setRequestHeader("If-Modified-Since", last_modified);
           },
           url: '/test/sub',
           dataType: 'text',
           type: 'get',
           cache: 'false',
           success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
                     /*REMOVED CODE*/
               });

               /* Start the next long poll. */
               listen(last_modified, etag);
           },
           error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown)
           {
             //$('#data').prepend(textStatus + ' | ' + errorThrown);
           }
       }); 
   }; 

   google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
       /* Start the first long poll. */
       /* setTimeout is required to let the browser know
          the page is finished loading. */
       setTimeout(function() {
           listen('Thu, 1 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT', '0');
       }, 500);
   });
    //alert(1);
    $('#winners tr').click(function() {
      alert(223);
    });
  </script>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `CTRF+F5` each time you refresh the page

Comment: You should put your event listener in document.ready function to make sure your dom is ready.

Comment: As you are using `google.load("jquery", "1.7.1");`, thus had to to use callback, read docs https://developers.google.com/loader/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that your code is executed before the element is present in the DOM so `$('#winners tr')` is empty unless you have this alert blocking the script.

The usual solution is to put the whole `script` element at the end of the `body` element instead of inside the `head`. Or you could wrap your code in a jquery ready event handler.

As you're using google load, the best here would be to move the click binding code inside the callback you pass to `google.setOnLoadCallback`.

Comment: Document ready will not works as OP is using `google.load("jquery", "1.7.1");`, thus had to to use callback

Answer (score 1):

If your code is in the head of the page place it in a document ready handler -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function listen(last_modified, etag) {
       $.ajax({
           'beforeSend': function(xhr) {
               xhr.setRequestHeader("If-None-Match", etag);
               xhr.setRequestHeader("If-Modified-Since", last_modified);
           },
           url: '/test/sub',
           dataType: 'text',
           type: 'get',
           cache: 'false',
           success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
                     /*REMOVED CODE*/
               });

               /* Start the next long poll. */
               listen(last_modified, etag);
           },
           error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown)
           {
             //$('#data').prepend(textStatus + ' | ' + errorThrown);
           }
       }); 
   }; 

   google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
       /* Start the first long poll. */
       /* setTimeout is required to let the browser know
          the page is finished loading. */
       setTimeout(function() {
           listen('Thu, 1 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT', '0');
       }, 500);
   });
    //alert(1);
    $('#winners tr').click(function() {
      alert(223);
    });
});
```